# GCS_WGS_1984 and 900913. What is the difference?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, wms, mapproxy

I use WMS Service with mymapproxy/mapproxy.yaml :

```
services:
  demo:
  kml:
  tms:
  wmts:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913']
    md:
      title: MapProxy OSM WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is the fantastic MapProxy.
layers:
  - name: osm
    title: Local OSM WMS
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [global_mercator_osm, global_geodetic_sqrt2]
    sources: [osm_mapnik2]

sources:
  osm_mapnik:
    type: mapnik
    mapfile: /home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml
  osm_mapnik2:
    type: tile
    grid: global_mercator_osm
    url: http://localhost/osm_tiles/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png

grids:
  global_mercator_osm:
    base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
    srs: 'EPSG:900913'
    origin: nw
  global_geodetic_sqrt2:
    base: GLOBAL_GEODETIC
    res_factor: 'sqrt2'
    srs: 'EPSG:900913'
    origin: nw
```

Then I display this WMS service in Geoserver. I **have not any problems** (if i set **Native и Declared SRS** as **900913**)

But I'd like display this service in ArcMap 10.1

This is the coordinate system of my ArcGis service.
[image]

So, I don't see the 900913 coordinate system. And when I add this service to TOC (left panel with layers in ArcMap) I have a lot of errrors:

[image]

[image]

Sometimes I do not see a map or this map is not good:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

EPSG 900913 is a spherical mercator projection which uses meters as its units.  EPSG 4326 uses a different datum and has its units are in degrees.  They are not interchangable and the difference in units will set your BBOX way off. If you can't find EPSG900913 try looking for EPSG3857 (which is the more up to date EPSG code for 900913).

Comment: is GCS_WGS_1989 relevant  EPSG 4326?

Comment: GCS stands for geographic coordinate system and GCS_WGS_84 (as per your original question) is EPSG 4326.  It is just a different way of referencing the same thing.  The EPSG codes are a bit more universal.  WGS84 is the name for both a datum and a coordinate system.  I'm not familiar with GCS_WGS_89 and there is no EPSG code for WGS89 so I assume this was a typo in your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. GCS_WGS_1984

So, I have map(as WMS Servise) with coordinate system 900913. But when I add this map in ArcMap I get message that coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984. (This message is display in picture "Layer Properties"). How I can change the coordinate system of my source (WMS Service)?

Comment: ArcGIS products cannot interpret 900913. It's not an EPSG well-known ID. See if GeoServer supports EPSG:3857 instead. As MappaGnosis says, it's equivalent to 900913.