# ArcMap 10.1 and MapProxy: what is the differense between WMS, WMTS and "Layer.OSM"

Tags: arcmap, wms, tile-map-service, mapproxy, wmts

On Ubuntu I have PostgreSQL, postgis, renderd, mapnik, mapproxy.

1) I have OSM. It is rendered by Mapnik.

2) Then I have MapProxy. So I have this OSM by WMS protocol.

3) I also can have this OSM by WMTS protocol (nowdays I do not use this protocol)

On Windows I have web-program on Aptana (OpenLayers) and ArcGis Server, ArcMap with Desktop application.

So on the OpenLayers I can display this map as:

- `new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("WMS", "http://192.168.36.139:8080/service?", {layers: 'osm'});` - It is WMS protocol. Here we see one picture.
- `new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM", "http://192.168.36.139/osm_tiles2/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19});` I do not know what this protocol is. Here we see the picture as many tiles.

Also we have ArcMap and Desktop Application, upgrading by me, based on ArcObjects.

I want to display this OSM here. So I add this OSM to ArcMap by WMS protocol. [GCS_WGS_1984 and 900913. What is the difference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72411/gcs-wgs-1984-and-900913-what-is-the-difference)
[Setting mouse wheel zooms in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73247/how-to-set-mouse-wheel-zooms-in-arcmap-10-1)

But ArcMap

1) Every time renders the OSM.

2) On the different scales does not display this OSM. And returns errors.

***So, my questions are:***

1) Do I solve this problems(with ArcMap), If I will use WMTS?

2) What is the difference between all this protocols?

Comment: I think your two questions should be two Questions. I recommend that you edit this one to focus on getting an Accept-able Answer to one or other of them first. Doing that may well resolve the other at the same time, or ask a New Question then if it does not.